# Two AutoCompleteBox controls in two different tabs in wpf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have used two AutoCompleteBox controls in two different tabs in a wpf window.

Control in first tab is working fine. [First Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldal.png)

But the control in second tab, data is binding and I could see the matched strings in the dropdown list.

**I couldn't select the items from the list using mouse or arrow keys.**  [Second Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cd9e.png)

When I moved the second control to new window, it is working fine.

I couldn't understand what is the actual issue?

Please find below code:

**Autocompletebox in first tab**

```
<ctrls:AutoCompleteBox  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtFirst" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
```

**Autocompletebox in Second tab**

```
<ctrls:AutoCompleteBox  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtSecond" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
```

**Xaml code for Tab control**

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1"
                    x:Name="tabCtrl"
                    SelectionChanged="tabCtrl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem x:Name="tab1"
                     Header="First">
                       <ScrollViewer>
                       <Grid>
                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="First"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                        <ctrls:AutoCompleteBox  Grid.Column="1"
                                                x:Name="txtFirst"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                      </Grid>
                      </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>        
            <TabItem x:Name="tab2"
                     Header="Second">
                       <ScrollViewer>
                       <Grid>
                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="500" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="Second"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                        <ctrls:AutoCompleteBox  Grid.Column="1"
                                                x:Name="txtSecond"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                       </Grid>
                      </ScrollViewer>
            </TabItem>        
 </TabControl>
```

**And the code behind**

```
var data = db.tblname.Select(c => c.propertyname).ToList();
txtFirst.ItemsSource = data;

var data1 = db.tblname.Select(c => c.propertyname).ToList();
txtSecond.ItemsSource = data1;
```

Comment: We can't really help you without you showing us your code..

Comment: @CodingMadeEasy I have posted the code. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough debugging of my code, I figured out that the issue was due to SelectionChanged event of TabControl.

Whenever I select an item from the Autocompletebox control, SelectionChanged event of TabControl was getting fired, which led to chaos, as my binding logic for Autocompletebox was in SelectionChanged event.

Still I am not getting why do my Autocompletebox control triggers SelectionChanged event of TabControl without the registeration of SelectionChanged event for Autocompletebox Control.

**But Below code overcame the issue**

```
private void tabCtrl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is TabControl)
            {
              // Business logic for binding autocompletebox
            }
        }
```

Thanks everyone for their support!

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code is fine.

You should take a look at the XAML.

(Provide XAML to us as well.)

Comment: I have posted the xaml code. Please have a look at the image for better understanding.Thanks

Comment: @jayakrishnanGounder It seems like your XAML is correct. Something blocks your Second Control. If you can provide ZIP with your project to DropBox/OneDrive/GoogleDrive temporary. I will take  a look,